# $\mathbf\triangledown\times\mathbf F=\mathbf 0$ implies $\mathbf F=\mathbf\triangledown\Phi$ denpends on whether it's simply-connected domain

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

How to prove $\mathbf F$ is conservative, i.e. $\mathbf F = \mathbf\triangledown\Phi$ by using the fact that $\mathbf \triangledown\times\mathbf F=\mathbf0$ implying $\mathbf F=\triangledown\Phi$ and the domain is a simply connected region

Actually I can prove the converse, i.e. $\mathbf F=\triangledown\Phi$ implies $\triangledown\times\mathbf F=\mathbf0$. But I cannot understand how we prove the other direction. Particularly, how does the constraint **simply-connected domain** work here?

Could anyone elaborate how we judge $\mathbf F$ is conservative or not by this principle with some concrete examples and reasons? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800214/irrotational-vector-field-may-be-written-as-grad-of-a-scalar-field?rq=1

Comment: Honestly, this is easier to explain with the machinery of differential forms: The question is basically why a simply-connected space has de Rham cohomology $H^1 = 0$. And that's fundamentally a topological question: $H^1$ is the abelization of the fundamental group, which is by definition trivial for a simply-connected space. The usual proofs of the OP are really just unwnding that machinery into more familiar terms, and it's tricky to be precise about the topological restrictions (especially since calculus texts can be sloppy about the hypotheses for Stokes' theorem and variants).

Comment: tl;dr version: This is actually a big question, and it drives a whole branch of topology and analysis. Fortunately, that branch has a lot of machinery and results to attack it with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [irrotational vector field may be written as grad of a scalar field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800214/irrotational-vector-field-may-be-written-as-grad-of-a-scalar-field)